# Rocket Chat and Kaseya BMS

Tags: rocket.chat

Has anyone successfully integrated Kaseya BMS and rocket Chat using the BMS API?

I would like to have a channel in rocket chat that is a feed of certain category tickets.

Having trouble figuring out how to get started as BMS documentation is sparse.